# What is going on in this piece of logic ? Java, parenthesis

Tags: java, logic

```
private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;

public void setTime(int h, int m, int s){
hour = ((h>=0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
}
```

from this mrbostons java tutorial:

https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=31&video=18001

Though you could (?) write the same code with a if statement, I'd like to know what is going on in this code and how I use it in other places

Comment: It's a short circuited `if-else` statement, known as a ternary operator. Basically, it's saying, `if (h >= 0 && h < 24) { hour = h; } else { hour = 0 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the equivalent of

```
hour = ((h>=0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
```

with `if/else`s :

```
if(h>=0 && h < 24) 
    hour = h;
else
    hour = 0;
```

The first notation is using a *ternary operator*.

Comment: And there is not need brackets here

Comment: **ternary operator** was the answer i was looking for. question answered

Comment: I don't check it, but are you sure that I can't write `hour = h>=0 && h < 24 ? h : 0;`

Comment: @v.ladynev you can do that actually.

Answer (score 1):

```
hour = ((h>=0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
```

if h is greater than or equal to zero, and less than 24, then set `hour` to the value of `h`, else set hour to zero.

Comment: thanks but I already knew **what** the code said but not **why**

Comment: ah, in you question you asked "what" the code is doing :-) To be fair I could also have mentioned that this is a ternary operator.

Comment: @KLibby  Yeah, **ternary operator** is the key of the David Blaine's magic